# VS2013 SP3 unable to update extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've installed recently VS2013 ultimate with SP3.

After install I've installed extensions but I can't upgrade any extension.

I click in the extension update button and nothing happen. I don't see any error in event viewer and I don't know why I can't update my extensions.

Note: I've also VS2012 ultimate SP4 and I can install and upgrade extensions.

Comment: SP3 is the latest update to VS2013. SP4 is only available to VS2012

Comment: SP4 is also available for VS2013